# Scala - How do I implement a generic copy method for case classes that extend an abstract class?

Tags: scala

I have an abstract class and some case classes that extend it:

```
abstract class Foo(
  a: Option[ABC],
  b: Option[DEF]
)

case class Bar(      
  a: Option[ABC] = None,
  b: Option[DEF] = None,
) extends Foo

case class Baz(      
  a: Option[ABC] = None,
  b: Option[DEF] = None,
) extends Foo
```

The fields of the case classes also extend a different trait:

```
sealed trait Alphabet

case class ABC extends Alphabet
case class DEF extends Alphabet
```

How can I implement a copy method that will work for all case classes (Bar and Baz)? Something like this does not compile:

```
  def copyBetter[T <: Foo](alpha: Alphabet, x: T): T = {
    alpha match {
      case cat: ABC =>
        x.copy(a = Some(cat))
      case cat: DEF =>
        x.copy(b = Some(cat))
    }
  }
```

Is there a natural way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you tried does not compile, because `x` is `Foo`, and `Foo` does not have `copy`. So, the short answer is you need to declare a `copy` method in the base class.

That gets a bit complicated though, because ... how do you specify the return type of that method? You want it to return the same type as the instance it is called on, but how does the base class know what type that is?
The trick you can use for this is called F-bounded polymorphism:

```
abstract class Foo[T <: Foo[T]](a: Option[ABC], b: Option[DEF]) { 
   def copy(a: Option[ABC] = a, b: Option[DEF] = b): T
}
```

Here, I added a type-parameter `T` which is basically "the type of the actual concrete subclass in question".

So, now we can define case classes like this:

```
case class Bar(a: Option[ABC] = None, b: Option[DEF] = None) 
   extends Foo[Bar](a, b)
case class Baz(a: Option[ABC] = None, b: Option[DEF] = None)
   extends Foo[Baz]
```

Notice, how each declaration specifies its own type as a parameter to Foo - that's how `Foo.copy` knows what to return.

So, now `betterCopy` is basically what you wrote:

```
def betterCopy[T <: Foo[T]](a: Alphabet, t: T): T = a match { 
   case a: ABC => t.copy(a = Some(a))
   case b: DEF => t.copy(b = Some(b))
}
```

Or, you could actually define it on the `Foo` itself:

```
abstract class Foo[T <: Foo[T]](a: Option[ABC], b: Option[DEF]) {
   def copy(a: Option[ABC] = a, b: Option[DEF] = b): T
   def betterCopy(x: Alphabet): T = x match { 
     case a: ABC => copy(a = Some(a))
     case b: DEF => copy(b = Some(b))
   }
}
```

Comment: My Bar and Baz case class would then need to be abstract correct?

Comment: No, why? They don't.

Comment: Asking because my compiler is telling me Class 'Bar' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member 'copy... Unless I am doing something wrong

Comment: Ahh I see, it is because my Bar class is actually something like case class Bar(
    id: String, a: Option[ABC] = None,
    b: Option[DEF] = None
) extends Foo[Bar] and my Baz class is actually something like case class Baz(
    id: Int, metadata: String, a: Option[ABC] = None,
    b: Option[DEF] = None
) extends Foo[Baz] - notice the id field is a different type and one case class has different fields vs the other. In this situation how do I get the code to compile?

Comment: then you can't. If there is no common `copy` method you subsclasses can inherit, obviously, you cannot define it in the superclass. 
You might be able to write a macro for that, but I can't help you here - don't know much about macros, personally, I think they are evil. There's also reflection ... but that's even more evil than macros ... You could also make a type-class, but that won't save you anything, because you'll still have to enumerate all the subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things:

- `trait` instead of `abstract class` - in a `case class` each parameter becomes `val` by default, but in a normal class it doesn't, so these parameters are basically useless in body of abstract class doesn't use them for anything. If outside world should see it, just define it as `val`s
- you can define `def copy` in the shape that both implementations would implement - it only works if both case classes would have the same shape, if they don't you'd have to declare and implement this abstract method yourself in each case
- you can use F-bound types and/or self types to make sure that this copy returns the same type as the type that implements it

Putting it all together we get:

```
sealed trait Alphabet
case class ABC() extends Alphabet
case class DEF() extends Alphabet

trait Foo[A] { this: A =>
  val a: Option[ABC]
  val b: Option[DEF]
  def copy(a: Option[ABC] = a, b: Option[DEF] = b): A
}

case class Bar(
    a: Option[ABC] = None,
    b: Option[DEF] = None
) extends Foo[Bar]

case class Baz(
    a: Option[ABC] = None,
    b: Option[DEF] = None
) extends Foo[Baz]

def copyBetter[A <: Foo[A]](alpha: Alphabet, x: A): A =
  alpha match {
    case cat: ABC =>
      x.copy(a = Some(cat))
    case cat: DEF =>
      x.copy(b = Some(cat))
  }

copyBetter(ABC(), Baz())
copyBetter(DEF(), Bar())
```

See [scastie example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/LoZ73zMNS0imE3UpxljBOQ/9).

Comment: My Bar and Baz case class would then need to be abstract correct?

Comment: No, why? I as you can see in the Scastie it compiles and runs for concrete Bar and Baz.

Comment: Asking because my compiler is telling me Class 'Bar' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member 'copy... Unless I am doing something wrong

Comment: Ahh I see, it is because my Bar class is actually something like case class Bar(
    id: String, a: Option[ABC] = None,
    b: Option[DEF] = None
) extends Foo[Bar] and my Baz class is actually something like case class Baz(
    id: Int, metadata: String, a: Option[ABC] = None,
    b: Option[DEF] = None
) extends Foo[Baz] - notice the id field is a different type and one case class has different fields vs the other. In this situation how do I get the code to compile?